# HTML5 Synchronise File System With Backend

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem

Actually I have to synchronise my local File System (Browser FS) with the server one each time I connect to the app:

Below is the root folder structure on the server that I get as a JSON Object:

```
{  
   "rootFolder":{           
      "childrens":[  
         {
            "path":"/RTW",
            "name":"RTW",
            "type":"DIR",
            "updateDate": "01/01/2015",
            "childrens":[  
               {
                  "path":"/RTW/rtw.pdf",
                  "name":"rtw",
                  "type":"PDF",
                  "updateDate":"02/01/2015"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  "path":"/Silk",
            "name":"Silk",
            "type":"DIR",
            "updateDate": "01/02/2015",
            "childrens":[  
               {
                  "name":"silk1",
                  "path":"/Silk/silk1.pdf",
                  "type":"PDF",
                  "updateDate":"02/02/2015"
               },
               {
                  "path":"/Silk/silk2.pdf",
                  "name":"silk2",
                  "type":"PDF",
                  "updateDate":"03/02/2015"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "path":"/Leather",
            "name":"Leather",
            "type":"DIR",
            "updateDate": "01/03/2015",
            "childrens":[  
               {
                  "path":"/Leather/leather1.pdf",
                  "name":"leather1",
                  "type":"PDF",
                  "updateDate":"02/03/2015"
               },
               {
                  "path":"/Leather/leather2.pdf",
                  "name":"leather2",
                  "type":"PDF",
                  "updateDate":"03/03/2015"
               },
               {
                  "path":"/Leather/leather3.pdf",
                  "name":"leather3",
                  "type":"PDF",
                  "updateDate":"04/03/2015"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "path":"/Soie",
            "name":"Soie",
            "type":"DIR",
            "updateDate": "0104/2015",
            "childrens":[
                {
                  "path":"/Soie/SoieSubdirectory",
                  "name":"SoieSubdirectory",
                  "type":"DIR",
                  "updateDate":"02/04/2015",
                  "childrens":[
                     {
                         "path":"/Soie/soie.pdf",
                         "name":"soie",
                         "type":"PDF",
                         "updateDate":"02/04/2015"
                     }
                   ]
                }
             ] 
         }
      ]     
   },
   "baseUrl":"https://int-myhpad-deu.atlas.hermes/Documents/FFR/180"
}
```

I have to compare the local file system structure with the root structure given by the JSON Object, Delete extra files or directories from the FS browser. If the file or directory is already on the file system, I have to compare the corresponding **updateDate** to decide if I download the folder or file again.

Thank you for your help in Advance.

Comment: so what is your question? how to compare the date?

Comment: here's a tutorial on how to use the FS object https://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/html5/articles/real-world-example-html5-filesystem-api.html

Comment: m8 if i'm right you need this http://gulpjs.com/

Comment: There is btw. an error in the date on this line `"updateDate": "0104/2015",`

Answer (score 0):

I think the flow must be the following:

1. Scan local filesystem for deleted files
2. Add/Overwrite/Skip server files

To scan the local filesystem and the JSON, the best way in my opinion is to use a recursive function with the two root nodes in input. I've no time to write down it now sorry :)